# PHP strtotime('UTC') different on another server

Tags: php, date, time, utc, strtotime

I have two different servers with a copy of the same PHP website.

Both servers are using the same timezone 'Pacific/Auckland'.

This code shows the same two numbers on server #1:

```
echo time();
echo strtotime('UTC');
```

1510607965 & 1510607965

But the same code is showing two different numbers on server #2:

1510607965 & 1510654765

Why would each server be different?

Comment: What time zone is _PHP_ using? You can find out with `date_default_timezone_get()` in a script. The difference in the two timestamps is 46800 seconds, which is 13 hours, which happens to be Auckland’s offset from UTC, so looks like one PHP installation is set to `UTC` (+0000) and another to `Pacific/Auckland` (+1300).

Comment: Didn't someone say this in the last question you asked (before you deleted it)?

Comment: @MartinBean date_default_timezone_get() is showing 'Pacific/Auckland' on both.

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem with the timezone database on one of the servers.

Comment: @Barmar they're both using the same PHP version. I'll try updating the timezone database.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `strtotime()` is supposed to be a string representing a timestamp, like `'Mon, 13 Nov 2017 15:30:24 -0800'` or `'2017-11-13 15:30:24'`. Passing the name of a time zone to this function, like `'UTC'`, will not yield a meaningful result.

Comment: I think this is more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both servers were using the same version of PHP but one of them had a problem with the timezone database.

I installed a new timezonedb and server #1 is showing the correct UTC time now.